# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string and return age with months

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I have function **[dbo].[MyAge]**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MyAge]
(
@DOB AS DATE,
@EndDate as DATE = '2999-01-01'
)

RETURNS TINYINT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Result as TINYINT
IF @EndDate = '2999-01-0'
SET @EndDate = GETDATE()
IF @DOB >= @EndDate
SET @Result = 0
ELSE
BEGIN
IF (MONTH(@EndDate)*100)+DAY(@EndDate) >= (MONTH(@DOB)*100)+DAY(@DOB)
SET @Result = DATEDIFF(Year,@DOB,@EndDate)
ELSE
SET @Result = DATEDIFF(Year,@DOB,@EndDate)-1
END
RETURN @Result
END
```

But when I select there appears error like in name of the topic. Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

```
DECLARE @dob datetime
SET @dob='19560109'
SELECT [dbo].[MyAge]( @dob,default )
```

I try to `SET @dob='1956-01-09'` but the same result appears
Or I try `SET DATEFORMAT ymd`;

And I wanna rebuild this function to calculate age in months and days but I can`t try to do it because of error.

Comment: your error is probably related to your using the word "default" in your select statement. Try using "SELECT dbo.MyAge (@dob, getdate())"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is, when you are comparing end date to **'2999-01-0'** this error, **Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string** is coming

try with this **'2999-01-01'**

It is working fine...

**do like this** 
IF @EndDate = '2999-01-01'

Comment: I believe you. Thanks. I can`t test it now. Size of disk on sqlfiddle.